# Какой стиль кодирования для C следует предпочесть?

Tags: css

Имеется в виду "code style": именования переменных, расстановка скобок, выравнивания. Где можно посмотреть своды правил по рекомендуемым стилям?

Answer (score 2):

Выбор желаемого стиля кодирования зависит от ряда факторов:

- новый или старый код,
- правила компании,
- личные вкусы разработчиков.

Важно не отобрать какой-либо конкретный стиль, а использовать единый стиль по всему проекту.